# cucumber-jvm java not generating step skeletons

Tags: eclipse, cucumber-jvm

Running in Eclipse Juno.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class RunTests {
}
```

In the console window I see:

```
Feature: Depositing money

Scenario: Sunny day [90m# deposit.feature:3[0m
Given: I have an Account with a balance of $100
When: I deposit $20
Then: The Account balance should be $120
```

Question: What is the [90m# and 3[0m about?

In target/cucumber/index.html, I see:

```
Feature: Depositing money
Scenario: Sunny day
Given: I have an Account with a balance of $100 
When: I deposit $20 
Then: The Account balance should be $120
```

I was assuming that if I run the tests on a new feature that does not have step definitions, that cucumber-jvm would spit out skeleton definitions for the steps that I could copy from the console window into a java file. Is that not how this works?

Comment: Have you been able to generate the Snippets and if so how? (I don't see that information here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber should provide step definition skeletons in the console window. Have you tried to run them from your terminal?

> Question: What is the [90m# and 3[0m about?

These are encoding to provide color. Probably due to your use of the PrettyFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

If you run with the option '--monochrome' you will not get the weird formatting `[90m# deposit.feature:3[0m`.
You can set this in your @CucumberOptions with monochrome = true or in the commandline using `--monochrome`